# How to open specific folder using my custom bash script

Tags: bash, unix, zsh

I need how to write a Bash script (not an alias) to navigate to my projects folder.

For instance, when I write (without any arguments)

```
$Projects
```

it should run the following command

```
$cd ~/Abdelrahamn/Projects
```

but if I write an argument like this

```
$Projects Proj1
```

it should run the following command

```
$cd ~/Abdelrahamn/Projects/Proj1
```

Comment: Do you use bash or zsh?

Comment: cd ~/Abdelrahamn/Projects/$1 would run the command in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script should have something like this:

```
cd ~/Abdelrahamn/Projects/$1
```

If a function inside `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` is accepted this would be as simple as:

```
Project() { cd ~/Abdelrahamn/Projects/$1; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need write a function to accomplish this and put it in your .bash_profile or .bashrc. Shell scripts execute in a subshell and once the script exits the subshell exits leaving you in the interactive shell.

```
Project () {
    project_path="/home/user/path/to/projects/"

    if [ $# -eq 1]; then
        cd "$project_path$1"
    else
        cd "$project_path"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need you a hash may be a good option. A whole script for this seems like overkill. In your ~/.zshrc.local (or earlier in whatever script is calling this), add:

```
hash -d project=~/Abdelrahamn/Projects
```

then you could use `cd` as you normally would call it, but with the nameddir/hash at the beginning. For example:

```
cd ~project
cd ~project/foo
```

would translate to:

```
cd ~/Abdelrahamn/Projects
cd ~/Abdelrahamn/Projects/foo
```